# Consumer Surplus

Tags: calculus, economics

I am working on an economics problem where my solution is not correct, and I'd like to know why. Below is the question and my subsequent work/solution:

> The demand function for a particular vacation package is 
>   $$D(q) = 2000 − 49\sqrt{q}.$$
>   Find the consumer surplus when the sales level for the package is $800$.

I got this far:

$$CS = \int_0^{800} 2000 - 49q^{1/2}- 614.07dq$$
$$ = \int_0^{800}1386 - 49q^{1/2} dq$$
$$ = 1386q - 24.5q^{-1/2}$$

Did I find the antiderivative incorrectly? I'm not sure what's wrong withn my work.

Comment: You might see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) about formatting math on this site.  Without that, you question is very difficult to read.

Comment: Hint: the height of the demand curve gives you willingness to pay for each unit. CS is the difference between that curve and the price the consumers actually paid on all the units that were consumed. However, I am not sure what "sales level" means. Is that price?

Comment: @Jaime What is the given soluttion ? I have an idea. But in my calculations the interim results have to be rounded and a third degree polynomial has to be solved. Thus I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\int q^{\frac{1}{2}} dq = \frac{2}{3} q^{\frac{3}{2}} + C$. So you integrated your second term incorrectly.

It should be:

$$\int_{0}^{800} (1386 - 49\sqrt{q}) dq = 1386(800) - \frac{98}{3} \cdot (800)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$